# how do you escape output with custom TUMBLR html themes

Tags: tumblr

background:
i am using javascript templates, which i would like to output raw, without tumblr replacing code matching their api variables

example:
i would like to literally output {Title} in the html, this is normally replaced by tumblr's html api as it is an api keyword, but usually templating systems have a raw/escape/unescape block functionality. This is not documented, but a lot of their functionality isn't either, such as the {host} tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found one way of doing it, exploiting the fact that tumblr does not support spaces in it's variable declarations: { title } does not get replaced, {title} does

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blog.post-theory.com/post/18173369734/tumblr-theme-limitations-when-a-block-doesnt-exist, you can do:

```
if ( [ {JSLinkUrl} ].length && [ {JSLinkUrl} ][0] ) {
    document.write('<a class="foo" title="bar" href="' + encodeURI( {JSLinkUrl} ) + '"></a>');
}
```

So I can guess that {JSTitle} Should work.